# Why do we need to use target "PROJECT_NAME" do from what version of cocoapods / xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoapods, xcode8, cocoapods-1.1.1

Recently in my new MACI've installed cocoa pods 1.2.1 i ran "pod update" in my projects Folder to update to the newest Version.

The result of the update is:

***`The dependency`FlurrySDK`is not used in any concrete target.`***

I've fixed the problem by adding pod like this

```
target "PROJECT_NAME" do

    pod 'FlurrySDK'

end
```

But Just for curiasity...

I want to know from which version of XCode / Cocoapods we need to add this line

***target "PROJECT_NAME"*** do

and Why

Can some one please clarify on this

Comment: CocoaPods configures your targets settings. SO you have to tell it which target to configure and how. For instance the test target typically needs additional frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

Your pod file will be like this, 
it is necessary to add your project name as "target".

Consider this code:

```
 # Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
   platform :ios, '8.0'
 # Uncomment this line if you're using Swift
 # use_frameworks!

 target 'PROJECT_NAME' do
 pod 'FlurrySDK'
 end
```

I hope it will help you, because i always add this for adding pods.
i think it is not XCode version based.